# Group by month and year

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, date-format

I am currently updating an old site where the date used in the database is formated dd/mm/yyyy.

What I am trying to do is group the rows by month and year. Is this possible with this formatting?

Comment: Dates don't have formatting, string representations of dates do.  Do you know if the field is a VARCHAR() or a DATETIME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always call STR_TO_DATE(value,'%d/%m/%Y').

Then you'll be able to group rows using ordinary date-extracting functions like YEAR() and MONTH().

Answer (score 0):

Whats the column type for the column where date is stored?
if its DateTime then you can do this:

```
group by YEAR(date_col), MONTH(date_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can `GROUP BY` with `substr` like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY substr(date, 4, 2)
```

where `substr(date, 4, 2) = MM` and if you want `dd` let's try `substr(date, 1, 2)`